# My Label doesn't contain all my results because of the size of the Label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, label

I have a problem with my label. It doesn't show all my data because sometimes the data is too long. How can i make it dynamically change it's size so that all my results will fit.Is it possible the UserControl or Pane size to cause this, because my Label is on a UserControl's Panel

Comment: Even if its on True i have the same problem.And appera only a few results.Is it possible the UserControl or Pane size to cause this, because my Label is on a UserControl's Panel

Answer (score 0):

Set the Label's [AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110)) Property to True:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is automatically
>   resized to display its entire contents.

```
lbl.AutoSize = True
```

---------- Edit ----------

> Even if its on True i have the same problem.And appera only a few
>   results.Is it possible the UserControl or Pane size to cause this,
>   because my Label is on a UserControl's Panel

The Label might be AutoSizing but gets clipped by the container it is in.  Either set AutoSize to True for the container(s), or consider setting [AutoScroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which would make scollbars appear in the Panel/UserControl.

Comment: Even if its on True i have the same problem.And appera only a few results.Is it possible the UserControl or Pane size to cause this, because my Label is on a UserControl's Panel